# Are "jede und jeder" combined together singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

> Jede und jeder hat/haben? eigene Probleme.

Please help.

Comment: Plural, analogous to „Ein Mann und eine Frau *haben* ...“ But may I ask, why you don't use the generic form *jeder hat* that includes both genders?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: not everybody considers "jeder" as a representation for all genders.

Comment: Because I read once that some females started to complain that "jeder", which is masculine, is always used. They wanted to add "jede", which is feminine, in everyday speech. Such a trivial thing to bother oneself with in my opinion.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm, still it is. Even if not, think about its implications: Would *jede und jede* make any sense? Well, it wouldn't! This phrase all the more splits the group into two subgroups by gender. But now, *one* subgroup, say that referred to by *jede*, does not comprise *all* anymore. In other words, *jede* is the wrong term for a subgroup that does not include *all*. The same deliberation applies to the other subgroup referred to by *jeder*. This in itself is a good reason why using the phrase *jede und jeder* does not make any sense.

Comment: Yes, you all have opinions on whether this is good usage or not. Fact is, people have different opinions on it and the usage exists. There is no point in having this discussion in the comments here.

Comment: How about using *alle*?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: "Jeder kann hier ein Marzipanbrot kaufen" kann man vor 1000 Leuten sagen, auch wenn man nur 100 Marzipanbrote hat. "Alle können hier ein Marzipanbrot kaufen" heißt, dass man auch 1000 Marzipanbrote hat.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: So what if those, who consider the term "jeder" nof sufficient for women and kids are wrong? Kids and girls (Kinder, Mädchen) are excluded from those, who have problems, because the words for them are neutrum, and obviously the speaker makes a distinction, based on the gender of words. Shouldn't a form like 'jedex' be used?

Comment: @MarioBedoun: The form is just wrong. Nonetheless, some pople will force you to use such wrong forms. Those people only pretend to not understand common German, when they encounter it. When they talk without carefully watching, what they are saying, they automatically fall back into proper German.

Comment: Why lecture someone asking a simple question about subject-verb-agreement on gender? The simplest way to avoid unnecessary discussion is to follow the guidelines and just describe usage instead of venting one's opinions: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340/35111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Jede und jeder* as a subject is combined with a singular form.

> Jede und jeder **kann** sich Coach nennen. [FAZ](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/stil/leib-seele/sex-smileys-und-spiritualitaet-wie-viel-darf-die-erleuchtung-kosten-16747029.html)
>
> Jede und jeder **soll** im Bezirk seinen Platz finden […] [NDR.de](https://www.ndr.de/nachrichten/hamburg/Bezirk-Hamburg-Nord-Gruen-rote-Koalition-steht,hamburgnord142.html)
>
> Jede und jeder **durfte** frei entscheiden. [DLF Nova](https://www.deutschlandfunknova.de/beitrag/mariana-harder-k%C3%BChnel-afd-politikerin-f%C3%A4llt-als-vizepr%C3%A4sidentin-durch)
>
> Hier **kämpft** jeder und jede für sich allein. [BZ](https://www.berliner-zeitung.de/politik-gesellschaft/kommentar-die-krise-ist-die-zeit-der-macker-li.79348)
>
> Jeder und jede von uns **wird** diesen Schmerz eines Tages kennenlernen und eine Krise durchleben. [Spiegel](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/kunst-ueber-trauer-stell-dich-dem-tod-baby-a-391da928-88fb-43b3-9958-66cdbf2ea24a)
>
> [J]ede und jeder **hat** das Recht hat zu wissen, ob und wo Maschinen Informationen sammeln und verarbeiten […] [FR](https://www.fr.de/meinung/jahre-volksrepublik-china-menschenrecht-daten-13054642.html)
>
> So wie unterschiedslos jeder von uns von dem Virus
>   betroffen sein kann, so **muss** jetzt auch jede und jeder helfen. [Angela Merkel](https://www.bundesregierung.de/resource/blob/975232/1732182/d4af29ba76f62f61f1320c32d39a7383/fernsehansprache-von-bundeskanzlerin-angela-merkel-data.pdf?download=1)

I assume the reason for this is the semantics of the pronoun *jed-*, which does not have plural forms.

Let's add some older quotations in order to show that *jeder und jede* is no recent invention and has been used by a variety of authors.

> Jeder und jede **dachte** nach, ob es denn keinen Weg der Rettung gebe […] [Karl May](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/May,+Karl/Jugenderz%C3%A4hlungen/Der+Oelprinz/2.+Kapitel.+Im+Mogollongebirge)
>
> Alt und jung war beisammen, jeder und jede **hatte** ein blasses finsteres Gesicht, nur der Metzger hatte ein rotes. [Rosegger](https://books.google.de/books?id=ojsTAwAAQBAJ&q=%22jeder%20und%20jede%22)
>
> Diesen hier **mußte** wohl jeder und jede schön finden. [Spielhagen](https://books.google.de/books?id=vvLsP5GPYNkC&q=%22jeder%20und%20jede%22)
>
> So **hatte** jeder und jede in Blumenau etwas
>   zu ertheilt erhalten, was einen voruͤbergehenden
>   Kummer verurſachte. [Clauren](http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/clauren_liebe_1827/?p=113)
>
> Sonst reisten bevorzugte Individuen, jetzt **reist** jeder und jede. [Fontane](http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/fontane_reise_1894/?p=5)
>
> daß […] nämlich: Jede und Jeder es **versuchte**, in ganz aufrichtiger Weise die eigenen körperlichen und geistigen Eigenschaften, Gewohnheiten und Gebrechen niederzuschreiben […] [Lexikon der katholischen Dichter](https://books.google.de/books?id=4R0TAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22jede%20und%20jeder%22&pg=PA311)

Comment: I assume the downvote is from someone who dislikes the fact that people use this form or thinks they should not use it. However, since I have described the usage correctly, I do not feel a downvote is warranted.