# Ist eine Bezeichnung mit "& Co" Singular oder Plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Ich habe den Titel "Wie Google & Co. deine Daten zu Geld macht/machen!".

Ist Google & Co. hier Singular oder Plural, und muss dann am Ende macht oder machen stehen?

Comment: Google und Co sind doch mindestens zwei, also Plural.

Comment: Ähnliche Frage mit ausgeschriebenem *und*: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/58583/1696

Answer (score 12):

Das ist hier die Ausnahme von der Ausnahme von der Regel.

"&" bedeutet "und". "X und Y" bezeichnet zwei oder mehr Personen oder Dinge und
verlangt deshalb die Pluralform des Verbs.

**Aber:** Das "&"-Zeichen ist im Deutschen eigentlich nur bei Firmennamen üblich,
erst recht in der Zusammensetzung "& Co". "X & Co" bezeichnet das Unternehmen, das
von X und anderen Gesellschaftern gegründet wurde. Die Gründung kann auch zweihundert
Jahre zurückliegen; man sollte also nicht davon ausgehen, daß X und seine
Gesellschafter noch im Unternehmen tätig sind. "X & Co" wird deshalb weniger als
eine *Gruppe* von Personen verstanden (was den Plural erfordern würde), sondern als
*ein* Unternehmen. Deshalb ist hier der Singular üblich. Ein paar zufällig
gegoogelte Beispiele:

> Klöckner & Co. ist der größte Stahlhändler in Europa, der über keine eigene Stahlproduktion verfügt.
>
> Lynk & Co ist Teil der Geely Holding.
>
> Tiffany & Co. ist ein 1837 in New York City gegründeter Juwelier aus den Vereinigten Staaten.

**Aber:** Bei "Google & Co" wird "& Co" im übertragenen Sinne benutzt. "Google & Co" meint nicht *ein* Unternehmen, sondern "Google und andere IT-Unternehmen". Deswegen ist doch wieder der Plural angebracht.

Comment: Ich würde hier widersprechen und "Klöckner & Co." als Eigennamen verstehen. Also keine Ausnahme sondern ganz normale Regel. Das die Bezeichnung  "... & Co (KG)" ein im Deutschen übliche Gesellschaftsform ist, ist ein Wertvoller Hinweis, im Kontext der Frage aber eigentlich bedeutungslos. Genauso sind KG´s AG´s und oft auch GmbH Unternehmensformen hinter denen regelmäßig eine Gruppe von Gesellschaftern steht. Auch hier gilt aber wenn man von der Firma spricht, eine einzelne (legale) Person also Singular.

Answer (score 1):

„Google & Co“ verlangt den Plural und es muss heißen:

> Wie Google & Co deine Daten zu Geld machen!

Answer (score 1):

Die Bezeichnung *»& Co«* lautet ausgeschrieben *»und Compagnie«* und kann gar nicht alleine stehen. Sie ist ein Teil einer Aufzählung und besteht aus der Konjunktion *»und«* und dem Listenelement *»Compagnie«.* (*»Compagnie«* bedeutet eigentlich *»Teilhaber, Gesellschafter«,* wird hier aber im Sinn von *»andere Unternehmen in derselben Branche«* verwendet.) Zusammen ergeben die beiden Wörter kein vollständiges grammatikalisches Element. Man kann jedes Wort für sich klassifizieren oder man kann die ganze Aufzählung betrachten in der diese beiden Wörter enthalten sind, aber die Frage, ob *»& Co«* Singular oder Plural verlangt ist schlichtweg unsinnig.

Nachdem *»& Co«* aber nur innerhalb einer Aufzählung Sinn macht und nur dort verwendet werden kann, ist klar, dass eine Aufzählung vorliegt, die mit den (abgekürzten) Worten *»und Compagnie«* endet. Das fundamentale Wesen einer Aufzählung ist aber, dass sie zwei oder mehr Elemente enthält, also nicht 1 Ding ist. Daher verlangt jede Auszählung, die als Subjekt in einem Satz steht immer, dass das finite Verb den Umstand berücksichtigt, dass von mehreren Dinge die Rede ist, und das heißt nichts andres, als dass das Verb dann im Plural stehen muss.

**Aufzählungen als Subjekt:**

> Hans und Ulrike <del>*isst*</del> **essen.**
> Deutschland, Italien und Frankreich <del>*grenzt*</del> **grenzen** an die Schweiz.
> Google und Compagnie <del>*macht*</del> **machen** deine Daten zu Geld.
> Google & Co <del>*macht*</del> **machen** deine Daten zu Geld.

Comment: Wie fast immer, eine ausführliche und sachlich korrekte und logische Antwort von Hubert, die aber anstrengend zu lesen ist und kein tl;dr enthält. Daher gebe ich kein hochvote.

Answer (score 1):

Die vorliegenden Antworten weisen zurecht darauf hin, dass das "& Co."  ursprünglich bei Firmennamen verwendet wurde und eigentlich eine Pluralform ist. Das ist allerdings in vielen Fällen in den Hintergrund getreten und man betrachtet die ganze Kombination als eine Einheit, die dann in der Singularform erscheint. Ein ähnliches Phänomen tritt bei Firmenbezeichnungen wie C&A oder H&M auf. Weitere Beispiele dieser Art sind Namen der Form "& Sohn" bzw. "& Söhne".

Unabhängig davon wird das "& Co." landläufig auch als "und seines/ihresgleichen" oder "und Konsorten" (durchaus im negativen Sinn "und Spießgesellen" bzw. "und Kumpane") verstanden - und es ist hierbei natürlich der Plural zu verwenden. Genau diese Interpretation trifft bei "Google & Co." zu.